# Custom TableView cell dequeue fatal error: unexpectedly found nil

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

## The setup

I'm trying to customise a prototype cell. Here's the cell in my main storyboard.

[image]

I have a custom cell class.

```
class UserListTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateCreatedLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateOfLastLoginLabel: UILabel!
}
```

It is linked up with the prototype cell in the same storyboard.

[image]

And just to be sure, here's the custom class name in the inspector.

[image]

Finally, in my view controller, I have the following extension that implements the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol.

```
extension UserListViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return users.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("userListCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UserListTableViewCell
        cell.nameLabel.text = users[indexPath.row].name
        return cell
    }
}
```

Along with the `viewDidLoad` method.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.tableHeaderView = tableHeaderView
    tableView.registerClass(UserListTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "userListCell")
}
```

## The problem

When I launch this in the simulator I get a runtime crash with `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. In the stack trace all of my labels are `nil`.

What's going on here and how can I fix this?

Comment: I assume that you have setup the cell identifier `userListCell`

Comment: @Aladin, yes I have, it felt a bit redundant taking a screen of that too :).

Comment: Don't call registerClass() if you are using Storyboard prototype cells.

Comment: @MartinR this is the correct answer, could you post this down bellow? Also, I'm curious as to why this is the case.

Comment: @MorganWilde: Actually this has been answered more than once before, I have linked to the first one that I found.

Comment: Thanks! Although that question doesn't have a substantive answer, it's only as good as your comment.

Comment: You don't call it because cells registered using registerClass() are created using `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` which doesn't load anything from your storyboard.

Comment: @MorganWilde: OK, I have tried to summarize the above comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Storyboard prototype cells are automatically registered to be used
with `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier()`. If no cell is available for
reuse, a new one will be instantiated from the prototype cell (using `initWithCoder:`), with all the labels and other elements that you
defined in the Storyboard.

With

```
tableView.registerClass(UserListTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "userListCell")
```

you *replace* the registration of the prototype cell. Now
`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier()` will create an instance of
`UserListTableViewCell` (using `initWithStyle:` as @dan said). But there
is no connection to the prototype cell, so the labels and other elements
are not created. In your case, `cell.nameLabel` is `nil`, and therefore
accessing `cell.nameLabel.text` throws the exception.